# How to design a web container in an android application

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm a newbie android programmer. So, I now meet a problem need your help.

I need a screen like the picture bellow.

[image: Three buttons must be put in the bottom of screen]

So, which layout I can use ? A full xml code is really cool for me.

Thanks you.

Comment: Use relative layout..

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? Do you already have some code (even not working)?

Comment: Thanks for your question. I tried in a half of day but did not success.

Answer (score 0):

use linear layout with weight property